# Responsive form

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

[image]

This form is for logging in, and as it appears on the first interface, the form is very nice, but when I reduce the screen it becomes like the second image, meaning it is a very bad interface.
The question is how can I solve the problem, ie I want to not write out of form when I zoom out.
Registeration.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="bg">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row class="padding">
        <v-flex xs4 sm5 offset-sm3>
          <v-card
            class="mx-auto mt-5 pa-5 text-center secondary text-no-wrap"
            max-width="1000"
            id="limited-products"
          >
            <div class="padding-bottom padding-top">
              ___________________________ or __________________________
            </div>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <form>
                  <v-layout row>
                    <v-flex xs12>
                      <v-text-field
                        label="name"
                        v-model="name"
                        type="text"
                        outlined
                        dense
                        required
                        color="#ffffff"
                        class="myfont"
                      >
                        {{ name }}
                      </v-text-field>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>

                  <v-layout row>
                    <v-flex xs12>
                      <v-text-field
                        label="email"
                        v-model="email"
                        type="text"
                        outlined
                        dense
                        required
                        color="#ffffff"
                        class="myfont"
                      >
                        {{ email }}
                      </v-text-field>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>

                  <v-layout row>
                    <v-flex xs12>
                      <v-text-field
                        label="password"
                        v-model="password"
                        type="text"
                        outlined
                        dense
                        required
                        color="#ffffff"
                        class="myfont"
                      >
                        {{ password }}
                      </v-text-field>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>

                  <v-layout row>
                    <v-flex xs12>
                      <v-btn class="red accent-4 color myfont" block>
                        Sign up
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>
                </form>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>
            <!-- ///////////////// -->
            

            
            <div class="padding-bot">Have you an account?</div>
            <h5 class="padding-down textColor text-caption text-sm-body-2" text-caption>
              This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google Privacy Policy
              and
            </h5>
            <h5 class="padding-bottom text-caption text-sm-body-2" text-caption>Terms of Service apply.</h5>

            <!-- //////////////// -->
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["SIGNUP"]),
    onSignUp() {
      const data = {
        name: this.name,
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
      };
      console.log(data);
      this.SIGNUP(data)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("SignUp Is successed");
          this.$router.push("/signin");
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.myfont {
  font-family: "Mansalva", cursive;
}
.margine {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.color {
  color: #fafafa;
}

.textColor {
  color: blanchedalmond;
}

.padding {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.size {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.paddingLeft {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.padding-down {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.padding-bot {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.padding-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: scale(1);
}
</style>
```

Comment: without the CSS and which library is provide all the custom tag it will be hard to help you

Comment: try to remove `offset-sm3` from the 5th line